# Efficient way to check if a large matrix is positive definite.

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, positive-definite

Suppose I have a large $n\times{}n$ matrix with $n>1000$ say. I would like to find the quickest way to check if it is positive definite. My matrices are sparse so at the moment I am using sparse matrices in Matlab and the command 'chol'. Is there a quicker way (preferably in Matlab)? Thanks!

My matrices are banded, if that helps.

Comment: Check that all eigenvalues are positive. If the matrix is real, it is even simpler; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Characterizations

Comment: That's slower than Cholesky factorization, I'm not bothered about eigenvalues, just the quickest way to see if it's positive definite.

Comment: You can check the quadratic form on, say, the standard basis in cubic time. And you can do it in parallel. Is that adequate? I'm not sure how much better you can do without some restrictions on the matrix you're talking about.

Comment: @Mathmo: did you see the comment on Wikipedia about using Descartes rule of signs when the matrix is real?

Comment: [Computational Science StackExchange](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com) might be a better venue for this question.

Comment: Are your matrices Toeplitz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general computing the Cholesky factorization of a symmetric matrix A is the fastest method to check if A is positive definite.

For banded matrices there is a specialized algorithm of computing the Cholesky factorization, which is faster than the Cholesky factorization of a sparse matrix. Such algorithm is not available in Matlab.

Symmetric positive definite matrices have positive elements on the main diagonal.

You may also apply the Gershgorin circle theorem to find constraints on eigenvalues of A. If this theorem shows that all eigenvalues are positive, then it proves, that the matrix A is positive definite.

The last two methods are very fast and can be used as fast checks, but do not work in general.